# Linux + kernel tuning parameters

Tags: linux, rhel, sysctl

I configured the following parametersbut after restart the values return to the previews values.

How to configure them as permanent?

```
 echo 500 > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_expire_centisecs
 echo 3 >  /proc/sys/vm/dirty_background_ratio
 echo 100 > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_writeback_centisecs
```

by the way the parameters dont exist in this file

```
more /etc/sysctl.conf
# /etc/sysctl.conf
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 1
net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_source_route = 0
kernel.sysrq = 0
kernel.core_uses_pid = 1
kernel.shmall = 5767168
kernel.shmmax = 4294967295
kernel.shmmni = 4096
kernel.sem = 250 32000 100 128
fs.file-max = 6815744
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 1024 65000
net.core.rmem_default = 1048576
net.core.rmem_max = 4194304
net.core.wmem_default = 1048576
net.core.wmem_max = 4194304
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_r
```

Comment: then write into it.

Comment: how ? please give an example?

Comment: like - dirty_expire_centisecs = 500    ??

Comment: if I run the sysctl -a , I get more then 100 parameters but in sysctl.conf I have only ~20 ?

Comment: `sysctl -a` gives you all the active kernel parameters, `sysctl.conf` are the ones you have customised in your environment.  Mine got around ~60-70. `vm.dirty_expire_centisecs = 1000`